# Representation of parent child relationship with dependencies

Tags: java, android, oop, structure, relationship

In an Android app I'm developing, I'm not quite sure if the way I thought the model structure should be is the best in terms of ease of use and low complexity.

I need to represent the following relationship:

- `TypeA` (could be seen as a vault, just one throughout the program) holds all objects of `TypeB`
- Every `TypeB` (of which there can be 0..*) can hold objects of `TypeC`
- Every `TypeC` (related to `TypeB`; 0..*) can hold objects of `TypeD`
- `TypeD` (related to `TypeC`, 0..*)

As there cannot be instances of either TypeC or TypeD without them being strongly related to a defined parent, I thought of the following structure (not including member variables such as title-`String`s, program related `boolean`s for view `CheckBox`es, …:

- `TypeA`: `Singleton`

  - member: `ArrayList<TypeB>`
  - methods: `addTypeB(UUID)`, `removeTypeB(UUID)`, `getTypeBs`, `getTypeB(UUID)`
- `TypeB`: `class`

  - member: `ArrayList<TypeC>`, `UUID mId`
  - methods: `addTypeC(UUID)`, `removeTypeC(UUID)`, `getTypeCs`, `getTypeC(UUID)`
- `TypeC`: `class`

  - member: `ArrayList<TypeD>`, `UUID mId`, `UUID mParentTypeBId`
  - methods: `addTypeD(UUID)`, `removeTypeD(UUID)`, `getTypeDs`, `getTypeD(UUID)`
- `TypeD`: `class`

  - member: `UUID mId`, `UUID mParentTypeBId`, `UUID mParentTypeCId`

I have already implemented the above structure using said four classes—one singleton, three "normal" classes—but am not too happy with the results at some points. For a particular instance of TypeD, I would have to type assignments like:

```
mTypeD= TypeA.getInstance(getActivity())
                         .getTypeB(typeBId)
                         .getTypeC(typeCId)
                         .getTypeD(typeDId);
```

Is there a better way to get the given relationship—or basically any relationship of that kind—into code? Probably the question isn't even Java-specific but instead relates to many object oriented programming languages.

**EDIT**: I have three ListViews for each type above TypeA, i.e., TypeB, TypeC, TypeD, containing all current instances and the possibility to open detail views for each single instance of either type. That’s why I thought about using the schema I provided in the first place.

**EDIT2**: On starting the app, users are presented with an empty `ListView` if data has not yet been created. The `ListView` that opens on application start represents a list of all instances of TypeB that can be found in TypeA’s `ArrayList<TypeB>`. If the user taps on the “new” button on the ActionBar, a new instance of TypeB gets created and the user redirected that particular TypeB’s detail view. On leaving the detail view, s/he gets redirected back to the list of TypeB instances (at that point populated with only the one instance just created).

Upon tapping on one `TypeB` instance in the list, the user gets directed to a(n empty) `ListView` of `TypeC` instances that belong to the `TypeB` instance previously tapped on—without the connection to `TypeB`, the `TypeC` instances don’t make sense so it is crucial to somehow have all instances of `TypeC` stored in a way that shows their relationship to a particular `TypeB` instance.

For `TypeC`->`TypeD` it is the same. Upon creating a `TypeC` instance in `TypeC` instances `ListView`, the `TypeC` detail view of the newly created `TypeC` instance is being opened, on pressing back the user gets redirected to the `ListView` of `TypeC` instances. On tapping on the TypeC instance, s/he gets to the (yet empty) `ListView` of `TypeD` instances—`TypeD` instances are also strongly related to a particular `TypeC` instance; without knowing the parent, they do not make sense.

For presenting the `ListViews` I let an `ArrayAdapter` go through all `ArrayList` items of the given type. For deleting (by long-pressing an item --> `ContextualActionBar`) or editing (same interaction as for previous action) I call the `.remove` method of the parent's `ArraylList` or open the detail view respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always denormalize data like this-  you don't need to just store it in 1 place, you can store it in multiple places.  For example, you can have a hashmap of UUID to TypeD objects that allows you to directly look up any typeD by UUID.  The catch is that you need to make sure to always update all the places you store it-  if you want to remove a type d and you have it in this tree structure and in a hashmap you need to remove it from both or your two views of the data will be out of sync.

Comment: Do you mean the hashmap as an additional means to my current structure? If I understood it right, I could then get a single instance of, e.g., `TypeD` by checking the hashmap for the specified UUID I passed to an Android activity/fragment; if I wanted to get all instances of `TypeD`s—which always belong to a certain instance of `TypeC`—, I would still have to consult `TypeC`'s—belonging to a certain instance of `TypeB`—`ArrayList<TypeD>`, specifying `TypeC`parent (TypeB) by its UUID. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  Of course you can also denormalize type C as well.  Its all a matter of how your app needs to access that data and what type of speed it needs.  For that matter you could even keep a separate array of all type Ds so you could loop through them-  but at that point you have yet a 3rd model of this data you need to keep in sync.

Comment: Really, you need to think about how your app will want to access the various data types, and decide what the best way to organize it is.  Its all a matter of complexity vs performance tradeoffs.  There's no one single answer.

Comment: I know—that’s why I asked in the first place as I was sure there would be other solutions. I have three ListViews for each type above TypeA containing all current instances and the possibility to open detail views for each single instance of either type. That’s why I thought about using the schema I provided in the first place.

Comment: So if you just want 3 list views and you want to be able to tap an item to view it, rather than the above just 3 lists should be good-  tapping on a list item would give you the position, giving you O(1) lookup time.  It's when you have frequent removals that it has issues.  If you want better advice, you need to give some idea of how frequently you want deletion, insertion, and the ratio of different types of access (do you normally go from B to C to D?  Normally look up a single B/C/D from the id?  Normally iterate over all of a single type? etc). Those answers greatly change our suggestions

Comment: I added additional pieces of information to my question